# Azure Storage: The lease ID specified did not match the lease ID for the blob

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Below exception logged in the application insights. We are using Blob Trigger and Cosmos DB trigger azure functions in our app.

> The lease ID specified did not match the lease ID for the blob
>
> [{"severityLevel":"Error","parsedStack":[{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common,
> Version=11.1.7.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor+d__1`1.MoveNext","level":0,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":1,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":2,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":3,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult","level":4,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.StorageBaseDistributedLockManager+SingletonLockHandle+<RenewAsync>d__17.MoveNext","level":5,"line":349,"fileName":"C:\\projects\\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\\src\\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage\\Singleton\\BlobLeaseDistributedLockManager.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":6,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":7,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":8,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult","level":9,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.SingletonManager+RenewLeaseCommand+d__4.MoveNext","level":10,"line":337,"fileName":"C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Singleton\SingletonManager.cs"},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":11,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":12,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":13,"line":0},{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult","level":14,"line":0},{"assembly":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host,
> Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35","method":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.TaskSeriesTimer+d__14.MoveNext","level":15,"line":147,"fileName":"C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Timers\TaskSeriesTimer.cs"}],"outerId":"0","message":"The
> lease ID specified did not match the lease ID for the
> blob.","type":"Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException","id":"57667516"}]

Blob Trigger Azure Function:

```
public static class ProcessEvent
    {
        [FunctionName(nameof(ProcessEvent))]
        public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger(BlobStorageContainer.Name + "/{name}",
            Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")]
            Stream eventBlob, string name,
            [Inject] ILoggingService loggingService,
            [Inject] IEventProcessDispatcher eventProcessor)
        {
            var logger = new Logger(loggingService);
            try
            {
                logger.Info($"Starting blob job tracker for file name {name}",
                    nameof(ProcessEvent));

                var eventContent = eventBlob.ReadAsString();

                await eventProcessor.HandleProcessor(eventContent, logger);

                logger.Info(
                    $"blob trigger function processed", nameof(ProcessEvent));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error($"Unable to process blob job for file with name: {name}", ex,
                    nameof(ProcessEvent));
            }
        }
    }
```

Cosmos DB Trigger Azure Function:

```
public static class NotificationChangeFeed
    {
        [FunctionName(nameof(NotificationChangeFeed))]
        public static async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: CosmosDBConstants.DataBaseName,
            collectionName: CosmosDBConstants.NotificationContainer,
            ConnectionStringSetting = CosmosDBConstants.ConnectionStringName,
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true,
            LeaseCollectionName = CosmosDBConstants.LeaseConainer)]IReadOnlyList<Document> input,
            [Inject] ILoggingService loggingService,
            [Inject] IEmailProcessor emailProcessor)
        {
            var logger = new Logger(loggingService);

            try
            {
                if (input != null && input.Count > 0)
                {
                    foreach (Document document in input)
                    {
                        string requestBody = document.ToString();
                        var notification = requestBody.AsPoco<Notification>();

                        await emailProcessor.HandleEmailAsync(notification, logger);
                        logger.Info($"Email Notification sent successfully for file name: {document.Id}");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.Error($"Unable to process Documents for Email Notification for Files: {input?.Count}", ex,
                    nameof(NotificationChangeFeed));
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Rakesh, did you ever resolve this problem? I am experiencing something similar in one of my environments

Comment: HI Rakesh and Phil, Did any of you find the solution for this? Even I am facing this issue in my azure v4 function.

Comment: @Naurto No solution found yet.